# nginx url rewriting: difference between break and last

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I don't understand the difference between break and last (flags of rewrite). The documentation is rather abstruse. I've tried to switch between the two in some of my configs, but I couldn't spot any difference in behavior. Can someone please explain these flags in more detail? Preferably with an example that shows different behavior when flipping one flag to another.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but please update the wiki.nginx.org when you get your answer. Also, the English-language nginx mailing list is quite active, and Igor (the main developer) answers hundreds of questions per month, so perhaps ask there.

Comment: @rmalayter - this question was asked on the nginx mailing list. Igor answered it but the answer didn't make much sense to me either: http://www.pubbs.net/nginx/200908/46047/

Comment: pubbs.net link is broken as the domain was taken over.  Sorry, was not able to find where it should point. ;(

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You may have different sets of rewrite rules for different locations. When rewrite module meets `last`, it stops processing the current set and the rewritten request is passed once again to find the appropriate location (and the new set of rewriting rules). If the rule ends with `break`, the rewriting also stops, but the rewritten request is not passed to another location.

That is, if there are two locations: loc1 and loc2, and there's a rewriting rule in loc1 that changes loc1 to loc2 AND ends with `last`, the request will be rewritten and passed to location loc2. If the rule ends with `break`, it will belong to location loc1.

Comment: You mean if the rewrite has the break flag it won't search for a matching location block, thus making it belong to location loc1.

Comment: Exactly. Fixed.

Answer (score 92):

OP preferred an example. Also, what @minaev wrote, was only a part of the story! So, here we go...

## Example 1: No (break or last) flags

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root 'path/to/somewhere';

    location / {
        echo 'finally matched location /';
    }

    location /notes {
        echo 'finally matched location /notes';
    }

    location /documents {
        echo 'finally matched location /documents';
    }

    rewrite ^/([^/]+.txt)$ /notes/$1;
    rewrite ^/notes/([^/]+.txt)$ /documents/$1;
}
```

### Result:

```
# curl example.com/test.txt
finally matched location /documents
```

### Explanation:

For `rewrite`, the flags are optional!

## Example 2: Outside location block (break or last)

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root 'path/to/somewhere';

    location / {
        echo 'finally matched location /';
    }

    location /notes {
        echo 'finally matched location /notes';
    }

    location /documents {
        echo 'finally matched location /documents';
    }

    rewrite ^/([^/]+.txt)$ /notes/$1 break; # or last
    rewrite ^/notes/([^/]+.txt)$ /documents/$1; # this is not parsed
}
```

### Result:

```
# curl example.com/test.txt
finally matched location /notes
```

### Explanation:

Outside the location block, both `break` and `last` behave in the exact manner...

- no more parsing of rewrite conditions
- Nginx internal engine goes to the next phase (searching for `location` match)

## Example 3: Inside location block - "break"

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root 'path/to/somewhere';

    location / {
        echo 'finally matched location /';
        rewrite ^/([^/]+.txt)$ /notes/$1 break;
        rewrite ^/notes/([^/]+.txt)$ /documents/$1; # this is not parsed
    }

    location /notes {
        echo 'finally matched location /notes';
    }

    location /documents {
        echo 'finally matched location /documents';
    }
}
```

### Result:

```
# curl example.com/test.txt
finally matched location /
```

### Explanation:

Inside a location block, `break` flag would do the following...

- no more parsing of rewrite conditions
- Nginx internal engine continues to parse the current `location` block

## Example 4: Inside location block - "last"

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root 'path/to/somewhere';

    location / {
        echo 'finally matched location /';
        rewrite ^/([^/]+.txt)$ /notes/$1 last;
        rewrite ^/notes/([^/]+.txt)$ /documents/$1;  # this is not parsed
    }

    location /notes {
        echo 'finally matched location /notes';
        rewrite ^/notes/([^/]+.txt)$ /documents/$1;
    }

    location /documents {
        echo 'finally matched location /documents';
    }
}
```

### Result:

```
# curl example.com/test.txt
finally matched location /documents
```

### Explanation:

Inside a location block, `last` flag would do the following...

- no more parsing of **current location context** of rewrite conditions
- Nginx internal engine **starts to look** for another location match based on the result of the `rewrite` result & applies rewrite rule in that location context

## Summary:

- When a `rewrite` condition with the flag `break` or `last` matches, Nginx stops parsing any more `rewrites`!
- Outside a location block, with `break` or `last`, Nginx does the same job (stops processing anymore rewrite conditions).
- Inside a location block, with `break`, Nginx only stops processing anymore rewrite conditions
- Inside a location block, with `last`, Nginx stops processing anymore rewrite conditions and then **starts to look** for a new matching of `location` block!

### Final Note:

I missed to include some more edge cases (actually common problem with rewrites, such as `500 internal error`). But, that'd be out of scope of this question. Probably, example 1 is out of scope, too!

Comment: **ERROR**: "nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code."... unknown directive "echo"

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/echo/ . Some Linux distributions such as Ubuntu 14.04 onwards bundle this module in certain packages (such as in nginx-extras). I hope that helps.

Comment: In example 1 would it make a difference if the rewrite rules were placed above the all three location directives?

Comment: @CraigHicks No, it wouldn't. A rewrite rule has higher precedence and is executed at first before locations are matched.

Comment: Can you possibly put more edge cases into a gist or something, and add a link to it?

Comment: This should be the best answer. It's easy to understand by referring to these examples, and reading the nginx documentation.

Comment: What about "permanent" ? Is it "permanent break" or "break permanent" or both or neither?

Comment: @PJBrunet As per the official docs that can be seen at https://nginx.org/r/rewrite, // An optional flag parameter can be **one** of last, break, redirect and permanent //. Basically, we can not use more than one flag for rewrite statement.

Comment: The best answer, finally understood regex and locations - can now re-write my tracking scripts and hide from adblockers.

Comment: it is such a brilliant explanation !!!!

Comment: Great explanation. But I think example 4 is incorrect, I tested it, it should be echo 'finally matched location /documents'. My Nginx version is 1.18.0

Comment: @Belive You are right. Just checked the example 4 with Nginx 1.18.0. Not sure when things changed (or my answer was wrong all along). Btw, you edit is under review. I didn't approve it because it didn't remove the comment `# this is not parsed, either!` on example 4. Would you like to edit it further (so that you get the credit for the correction)?

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu, just updated. Again, thanks for your thorough explanation :)