# Nginx Rewrite - purpose of specifying replacement url when using break flag

Tags: nginx

This question is an extension of [rewrite break vs last](https://serverfault.com/a/132320/249195). From what I understand the break statement will stop processing the current set of rewrite statements and instead of triggering a new location search, it would continue processing the rest of the statements in the current location block. If this is the case, what is the purpose of the replacement url given in the rewrite directive.

Comment: That will be value of `$uri` variable. It's used in proxy, fastcgi and some other things.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass there is example with rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matching rewrite rule is found a new URI is being composed using the specified rule.

With `break` keyword nginx uses the new URI within the location block rewrite was in.

So if there is nothing else in current `location` nginx will try to serve a file using a new URI. If you have a `proxy_pass` or something like that then it will forward a request with a new URI.

If `last` keyword is specified then after creating a new URI nginx "restarts" the process of request handling and triggers a new search over `location` blocks but new URI.

`last` and `break` are well documented in nginx documentation:

> **last** stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module
>   directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed
>   URI;
>
> **break** stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module
>   directives as with the break directive;

If rewrite rule appears in a server block then it seems that there is no difference between `last` and `break`.